# meteor-autoform cannot display form: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I try to create autoform with type `method` in my Meteor application.

Client side HTML:

```
<template name="addLeader">
   <div id="addLeader" class="addLeader">
      <h2></h2>
      {{#autoForm schema=LeaderSchema id="insertPostForm" type="method" meteormethod="serverMethod"}}
      {{> afQuickField name='userName' class='form-input'}}
      {{> afQuickField name='secondName' class='form-input'}}
      {{> afQuickField name='email' class='form-input'}}
      {{> afQuickField name='password' type='password' class='form-input'}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default full-width accept-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok "></span></button>
      {{/autoForm}}
      <button class="btn btn-default full-width cancel-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span></button>
   </div>
</template>
```

Client side JS:

```
Template.adminPanel.helpers({

    LeaderSchema: function() {
        return Schema.LeaderSchema;
    }
});
```

Schema in lib:

```
Schema = {};

Schema.LeaderSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    userName: {
        type: String,
        label: ""
    },
    secondName: {
        type: String,
        label: ""
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        label: ""
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        label: ""
    }
});
```

Server method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    serverMethod: function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    }
});
```

On view where I want to display form, form fields are not displaying, and i get this error:

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined
    at Object.getDefs (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?666ec8103d59fae9aad5553df832ececaa593358:255:18)
    at Object.autoFormGetComponentContext [as getComponentContext] (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?666ec8103d59fae9aad5553df832ececaa593358:516:20)
    at Object.afQuickFieldIsGroup (http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?666ec8103d59fae9aad5553df832ececaa593358:7489:30)
    at bindDataContext (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2880:16)
    at Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:1651:16)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2928:66
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:3476:12)
    at wrapHelper (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?a5c324925e5f6e800a4c618d71caf2848b53bf51:2927:27)
    at Object.Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:172:18)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?666ec8103d59fae9aad5553df832ececaa593358:7440:22
```

When I remove form fields from the html file, then I don't get errors. What could be reason? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm doing this with [autoform docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#non-collection-forms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the wrong template for your `LeaderSchema` helper.

This should work:

```
Template.addLeader.helpers({ // not Template.adminPanel.helpers
    LeaderSchema: function() {
        return Schema.LeaderSchema;
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, i had one main template and two templates nested in this one and I have not seen that. Thank You